# Last name capitalization of first letter

Tags: c#, string, formatting

So I get last name data in all caps from the database. I need to format the text to have the first letter of each part of the name capitalized. Currently I have the code below which accounts for people with double last names (ex. SMITH-JONES becomes Smith-Jones) but while checking the results I noticed I still have an error when it comes to names like VAN BEBBER which becomes Van bebber. Any suggestions?

```
var fullLast = Last.Split('-');
var lastFormatted = new StringBuilder();

for (var i = 0; i < fullLast.Length; i++)
{
    fullLast[i] = char.ToUpper(fullLast[i][0]) + fullLast[i].Substring(1).ToLower();
    lastFormatted.Append(fullLast[i]);
    if (i != fullLast.Length - 1)
        lastFormatted.Append("-");
}

return string.Format(
    "{0} {1}",
    char.ToUpper(First[0]) + First.Substring(1).ToLower(),
    lastFormatted);
```

Comment: What's preventing you from fixing this the same way as you fixed double last names? (I.e. splitting on both characters.)

Comment: .NET has a `ToTitleCase` method in it already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with names - things are extremely inconsistent. Read this article for more information: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names

In your example, you reference the last name "VAN BEBBER", which you want to be capitalized as "**V**an **B**ebber". However, as the article points out, there are other combinations from other areas of the world which would ruin most attempts at standardization - for instance, the last name "BIN OSMAN" would be properly capitalized as "bin **O**sman" - no capital "b" for "bin", which means "son of" and therefore doesn't fit well in the westernized concept of a last name.

You mention that you split last names by dashes, which most likely comes from the idea of a hyphenated last name - do you check the first name for dashes as well? The site gives the example name of "María-Jose Carreño Quiñones" - which is quite difficult to parse due to a double first name (separated by a hyphen) as well as a double last name (separated by a space). How would your program fair with that name?

To answer your question more directly, without bringing in more edge cases - you already know how to split a string via the dash - if you want to cover the case of last names with spaces, you should further split the last name string by spaces, and only then capitalize the first letter of the different split-up strings.

Alternatively, as Dai mentioned in a comment, you could use the `ToTitleCase` method - more information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase(v=vs.110).aspx This is most likely a better solution than trying to make your own. However, this page references the fact that not all languages capitalize in the same way (and indeed, different last names may come from different areas/cultures/languages), and therefore setting the correct language may not always yield the correct last name capitalization. Note that it would capitalize "BIN OSMAN" as "**B**in **O**sman", which is technically incorrect.

Here's a quick example from that page:

```
// Defines the String* with mixed casing.
String^ myString = "wAr aNd pEaCe";

// Creates a TextInfo based on the "en-US" culture.
/**** Personal Note - en-US may not be the correct culture for every last name! ****/
CultureInfo^ MyCI = gcnew CultureInfo( "en-US",false );
TextInfo^ myTI = MyCI->TextInfo;

// Changes a String* to lowercase. Outputs "War and Peace"
Console::WriteLine( "\"{0}\" to titlecase: {1}", myString, myTI->ToTitleCase( myString )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `ToTitleCase` method....

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture; //Or use a specific culture
var str1 = cultureInfo.TextInfo.ToTitleCase("VAN BEBBER".ToLower(cultureInfo));
var str2 = cultureInfo.TextInfo.ToTitleCase("SMITH-JONES".ToLower(cultureInfo));
```

Comment: var str3 = cultureInfo.TextInfo.ToTitleCase("Nancy O'Neill".ToLower());  hmmmmm....  r u sure this works?

Comment: It "works" based on a specific set of capitalization rules per language. "O'Neill" isn't actually an English word, so the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` may not contain a rule or set of rules that would cause it to be capitalized correctly. It's possible that no `culture` contains the correct rules for that example. It's a surprisingly difficult problem to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do a split by space and then by '-'.  That way you could capture all of the instances.

See this example:

```
var names = fullName.Split(' ');
        var formatted = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(string name in names)
        {
            if(name.Contains('-'))
            {
                var nonHyphanatedNames = name.Split('-');
                    foreach (var nonHyphanatedName in nonHyphanatedNames)
                    {
                        formatted.Append(char.ToUpper(nonHyphanatedName[0]) + nonHyphanatedName.Substring(1).ToLower() + '-');
                    }

            }
            else
            {
                formatted.Append(char.ToUpper(name[0]) + name.Substring(1).ToLower() + ' ');
            }


        }
        //remove last field
        formatted.Remove(formatted.Length - 1, 1);
        Console.Write(formatted);
```

Comment: This would certainly capture the instances that Desquid mentioned - however, as I mentioned in my answer, there are actually a lot of edge cases when it comes to names around the world. "Van Bebber" is just one such case.

Comment: Actually the code I supplied covers those edge cases as well. Since 'Van Bebber' is separated by a space(' '), it works

Comment: But does not cover such cases as "bin Osman" (from my answer) or O'Neill (from g2000's comment on another answer) - the point being that capitalization of names is unfortunately not as easy as "split by spaces and/or dashes, then capitalize"